Graduate-like ending for Route 66?
Just happened to catch the tail end of The Graduate on TV, and makes me recall the ending of a serial TV show, most likely Route 66, where a wedding in a church was interrupted by the protagonist and he and the ersatz bride ran off and, I think, hopped into the Corvette driven by the traveling companion.
But when I look at the episode summaries on Flickr I don't see anything matching that description.
Is Flikr missing some episodes, or am I remembering a different TV show, or did I imagine the whole thing?
(Note that Route 66 ran 1960-1964, and this is certainly the right era for this recollection.  And I think that this was the last (or maybe penultimate) episode of the series, though there was a discontinuity in characters and plot about a year earlier and it may have been then.  And I remember a closing scene where the three were, I think, near a dock, and the third wheel got out of the car (having crammed in the back) and said his goodbyes.  The other guy objected, said "You can come with us", but the response was "No, this car is a two-seater.)
OK, partly sorted it out.  Route 66 episodes 21 and 22, out of 24 total episodes, apparently (no clear for sure) include the marriage of Tod, his subsequent attempted murder, and the sorting out of this mess.  Unfortunately, the IMDB summaries don't describe this very well, so it's hard to say how much resemblance there is to The Graduate's wedding sequence.

We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing?   Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
